# How to clean autoload_classmap from previous mistakes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, composer-php

I'm using Laravel and composer with a auto generated database.
I have a python script that automaticly create and fill some tables. I used `php artisan code:models` to create Models for every of my table. But I made a mistake, some of my tables had '!' and that confused composer.

I fixed my python script, cleared my tables and recreate them. I removed all my Models and re executed `php artisan code:models`. But I still can't use them. It seems that I also have to check the auto_loads files in the vendor/composer/ folder.

I don't remember writting by hands theses files. Is there a way to update them ? Maybe deleting before `php artisan code:models`, but i'm too scared to touch them...

Portevent

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` would recreate the autoloader files, though I don't know if this should be necessary

Comment: "It seems" sound like you need to share more details. Usually, `autoload_classmap.php`  should not contain individual classes from your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing old class from autoload_classmap and autoload_static and using composer dump-autoload worked